# Laravel Testing auth middleware

Tags: laravel, integration-testing

When feature testing my app, I find myself writing pretty much the same tests to verify that my controllers require authentication. It usually looks something like this:

```
public function a_guest_cannot_view_any_of_the_pages()
{
    $this->withExceptionHandling();

    $model = factory(Model::class)->create();

    $response = $this->get(route('models.show', [ 'id' => $model->id ]));
    $response->assertRedirect(route('login'));

    $response = $this->get(route('models.edit', [ 'id' => $model->id ]));
    $response->assertRedirect(route('login'));

   ...etc 
}
```

However, I find it unnecessarily cumbersome to test it like this for every controller that requires authentication.

Is there any tactics for testin CRUD with auth middleware? How do I improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a data provider:

in tests/TestCase.php:

```
/**
* @dataProvide dataProvider
*/
public function testRedirectToAuth($routeName)
    {
    $this->withExceptionHandling();

    $model = factory(Model::class)->create();

    $response = $this->get(route($routeName, [ 'id' => $model->id ]));
    $response->assertRedirect(route('login'));
}
```

and then you can call it in all the test cases:

```
public function dataProvider()
{
  return [
    'model.show',
    'model.edit',
    ...
  ];
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely a good start. However, I think it should be possible to apply this globally. Now it is restricted to one Test-class.

Comment: add the function to TestCase class in the tests folder. all the test cases extend that class. I edited the answer to include them

Comment: I'll accept your answer since it is a good enough solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**
Define the middleware in the controller constructor that will act on all functions

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

ou
**Solution 2**
Define the middleware directly on the route

```
Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
    //
})->middleware('auth');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware

Comment: Thanks for answering. This answer is not related to the testing, but merely a pre-requisite for the auth middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ShowTrait`, when using this trait you have to specify your route and model name.

```
<?php

class ModelTest extends Test
{
    use ShowTrait;

    protected $routebase = 'api.v1.models.';
    protected $model = Model::class;
}

abstract class Test extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase, InteractsWithDatabase, UseAuthentication;

    protected $routebase = 'api.v1.';
    protected $model;

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function is_valid_model()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(class_exists($this->model));
    }
}

trait ShowTrait {

    public function test_show_as_authenticated_user()
    {
        $record = factory($this->model);

        $this->assertShow($record)
    }


    protected function assertShow($record)
    {
        $route = route($this->routebase . "show", ['id' => $record->id]);

        // Get response
        $response = $this->get($route);
        $response->assertRedirect(route('login'));
    }
}
```